# Doctrine select where equal to variable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony1

This is what I want to do:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
     ->where('c.categoryParentid = ?', $pcategory->getcategoryId())
     ->orderBy('c.categoryId', 'ASC')
     ->getQuery();

$childcategories = $query->getResult();
```

The `$pcategory->getcategoryId()` is an integer. The where, is this correct?
I get this error:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given in /Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs/reuzze/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Base.php line 92
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used that syntax before, but the Symfony docs have examples of [using the query builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#using-doctrine-s-query-builder), and they show something like this:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
 ->where('c.categoryParentid = :pcategory')
 ->setParameter('pcategory', $pcategory->getcategoryId())
 ->orderBy('c.categoryId', 'ASC')
 ->getQuery();
```

Comment: The property on your model should be categoryParent, and hold an object, not an id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [EntityRepository::findBy()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#144-158) method (outlined in the Symfony 2.x documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database)) which allows you to specify search criteria and sorting.

e.g.

```
$childCategories = $repository->findBy(array(
    'categoryParentId' => $pcategory->getCatagoryId()
  ),
  array(
    'categoryId' => 'ASC'
  )
);
```